# Merging time multiindex dataframes asof in pandas v.18.01

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multi-index

I have 2 data frames

```
date_1 = datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 1)
date_2 = datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 6)
t_ndx_1 = pd.date_range(date_1, periods=5, freq='30D')
t_ndx_2 = pd.date_range(date_2, periods=5, freq='30D')
index_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ndx_tuple).set_names(['date', 'sid'])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n*3), index=index_1, columns=['price'])
index_2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ndx_tuple2).set_names(['date', 'sid'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(n*3), index=index_2, columns=['factor'])    

print(df_1)
                   price
date       sid          
2008-07-01 baz  0.952190
           bar  0.151116
           foo  1.016207
2008-07-31 baz  0.651457
           bar -0.069647
           foo -0.307071
2008-08-30 baz -0.135290
           bar  1.782500
           foo  0.178755
2008-09-29 baz  1.871211
           bar  1.505863
           foo -1.749282
2008-10-29 baz -0.369726
           bar  1.754219
           foo -0.206260

print(df_2)
                factor
date       sid        
2008-07-06 baz       0
           bar       1
           foo       2
2008-08-05 baz       3
           bar       4
           foo       5
2008-09-04 baz       6
           bar       7
           foo       8
2008-10-04 baz       9
           bar      10
           foo      11
2008-11-03 baz      12
           bar      13
           foo      14
```

I'm trying to merge them to get analog merge_asof (I have pandas 18.01).
I found solution for simple DataFrame, without multiindex: http://genericfunct.blogspot.ru/2014/10/pandas-asof-join-sample.html

My solution:

```
def concat_asof(row, df):
    asof_date, sid = row.name
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    row = row.append(df.loc[idx[:asof_date, sid], :].iloc[-1])
    row.name = (asof_date, sid)
    return row

df_2.apply(lambda x: concat_asof(x, df_1), axis=1)
```

Out:

```
                factor     price
date       sid                  
2008-07-06 bar     1.0 -0.201496
           baz     0.0 -0.271080
           foo     2.0 -0.638019
2008-08-05 bar     4.0  1.253838
           baz     3.0  0.393520
           foo     5.0  0.682805
2008-09-04 bar     7.0  0.706282
           baz     6.0  1.431680
           foo     8.0 -1.169740
2008-10-04 bar    10.0  0.638859
           baz     9.0  0.330555
           foo    11.0 -1.221649
2008-11-03 bar    13.0 -0.507731
           baz    12.0 -0.221221
           foo    14.0  0.021257
```

Is there a nice solution for this task? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added my solution to the problem, but it's too heavy

Comment: Is not possible upgrade and use pandas [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) ?